# How to run my testng classes one after the other

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am running an automated test where i have two classes in a package. Below is my testng.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="AutomationFramework">
    <test name="RegressionTesting">
        <classes>
            <class name="first_Test.testng"/>
            <class name="first_Test.TestNG2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

my first class(testng) runs with Chrome, while the second (TestNG2) runs with Firefox. When I run my testng.xml file, I see both the browsers getting opened together and executing their test cases at the same time.

How can I prioritize that my first class runs in chrome and then when its finished, the second class runs.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code for launching of browsers?  By default parallel is set to none in Testng, so it's not Testng launching your tests in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the suite tag , add two attributes parallel="none" and limit the thread count to 1. The tag should look like

```
<suite name="AutomationFramework" parallel="false" thread-count="1">
```

This should disable the concurrent execution.